# How to plot multiple pie chart in Pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop, pie-chart

I selected categories from my data frame, please, see below, and need to plot pie charts for all categories. However, all data are plotted together on a single chart. Do you have any suggestions on how to solve it?

```
num_var = census.select_dtypes(include=['number']).columns.tolist()

num_var
```

['age',
'det_ind_code',
'det_occ_code',
'wage_per_hour',
'capital_gains',
'capital_losses',
'stock_dividends',
'continuous_?',
'num_emp',
'own_or_self',
'vet_benefits',
'weeks_worked',
'year']

```
for item in cat_var:
    census[item].value_counts().plot.pie(figsize=(10,10), fontsize=10, autopct="%.1f")

    plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just guessing you wanted to define `cat_var`, not `num_var`, right?

You did not share your data, so I created a small data frame `census` for demonstration purposes.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

census = pd.DataFrame({
    'country': ['CZ', 'CZ', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DE'],
    'age_group': ['0-18', '19-40', '40-65', '65-', '65-'],
    'job': ['astronaut', 'doctor', 'doctor', 'astronaut', 'astronaut']
})
census
```

To get all categorical variables, you might use

```
cat_var = census.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns.tolist()
cat_var
```

And to get a plot with several pie subplots, use the followig...

```
for i, var in enumerate(cat_var):
    plt.subplot(1, len(cat_var), i+1)
    census[var].value_counts().plot.pie(fontsize=10, figsize=(10,10), autopct="%.1f")
    plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')

plt.show()
```